# Как убрать пустой верхний правый угол из DataGrid при вертикальной прокрутке?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollview

В отличие от Windows Forms, где вертикальная полоса прокрутки занимает всю высоту DataGridView, в WPF DataGrid она занимает только область данных и не распространяется на заголовки колонок. В результате справа над полосой прокрутки появляется пустой угол, который плохо смотрится. Как это можно исправить?

В идеале хотелось бы решить вопрос минимальными усилиями, установкой какого-нибудь свойства. Но если это невозможно, то, может быть, это можно хотя бы поправить через шаблон, один раз прописать его в ресурсах приложения и забыть об этой проблеме?

[image: DataGrid]

````
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="85*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="287*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="LabelGrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Background="#FFF8F7F2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="19*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="725*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
...
<Grid  x:Name="MonthReport" IsEnabled="True" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column=" 1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Укажите нужный месяц и год" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextBlock.FontFamily="PT Sans" TextBlock.FontWeight="DemiBold" Margin="0,6.4"/>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="195*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="195*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="16"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="107*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="45*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="65*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxMonth" Grid.Column="0" Width="Auto" IsEditable="True" TextBlock.FontFamily="PT Sans"  TextBlock.Foreground="Black" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="Месяц" SelectionChanged="ComboboxSelected" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Background="#FFFFFFFF" Padding="16,6,0,6" />
                <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxYears"  Grid.Column="2"  IsEditable="True" TextBlock.FontFamily="PT Sans"  TextBlock.Foreground="Black" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="Год" SelectionChanged="ComboboxSelected" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Background="#FFFFFFFF" Padding="16,6,0,6" />
                <Button x:Name="GetMonthReportButton"  Height="Auto" Click="GetMonthReportButtonClick" IsEnabled="False" Content="Посчитать" TextBlock.FontFamily="PT Sans"  Grid.Column="4" Background="#FF5C3C86" BorderBrush="#FF5C3C86" Padding="14,4"/>
                <Button x:Name="SaveMonthReportButton" Height="Auto" Click="SaveMonthReportButtonClick" IsEnabled="False" Grid.Column="6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FF5C3C86" BorderBrush="#FF5C3C86">
                    <Image Source="Resources/SaveIcon.png"/>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <DataGrid x:Name="MonthReportMeetDataGrid" CanUserReorderColumns="False" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFE5E5E5"  Background="White" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" RowEditEnding="MonthReportMeetDataGrid_RowEditEnding" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Тип возвещателя" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left" CanUserSort="False" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Type}" Width="2*">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="ToolBar.Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontFamily" Value="PT Sans"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Сдало" TextBlock.FontSize="14"  CanUserSort="False" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding CountReports, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*" >
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="ToolBar.Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontFamily" Value="PT Sans"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Публ."  CanUserSort="False" TextBlock.FontSize="14"  CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding Publications}" >
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="ToolBar.Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontFamily" Value="PT Sans"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Видео"  CanUserSort="False" TextBlock.FontSize="14"  CanUserResize="False"  IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding Videos}" >
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="ToolBar.Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontFamily" Value="PT Sans"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Часы"   CanUserSort="False" TextBlock.FontSize="14"  IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding Hours}" >
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="ToolBar.Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontFamily" Value="PT Sans"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Повт. п."  CanUserResize="False" TextBlock.FontSize="14"  CanUserSort="False" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding ReturnVisits}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="ToolBar.Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontFamily" Value="PT Sans"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Изучения" CanUserSort="False" TextBlock.FontSize="14" CanUserResize="False"  IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding BibleStudy}" >
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="ToolBar.Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontFamily" Value="PT Sans"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
...
 </Grid>```
````

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Видно, что скроллбар не залезает на заголовок, а просто сдигает его влево, образуя дырку белого цвета. Выясните, что именно там в заголовке белого цвета и перекрасьте фон в нужный серый.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, указанная проблема решается следующим образом.

Если нужно просто убрать белый прямоугольник, то достаточно задать `DataGrid.Background` тем же цветом, который используется для фона колонок вместо `White`. Это свойство отвечает не за цвет ячеек, а за цвет пустого места в гриде, включая то, которое образуется при работе полос прокрутки.

Если нужно именно сделать так, чтобы вертикальная полоса прокрутки выглядела как в Windows Forms, то проще всего это можно сделать с использованием отрицательного значения верхней границы у полосы прокрутки. У меня корректно отработал следующий код:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Style.Resources>
        <local:GridConverter x:Key="gridConverter"/>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" 
                            Value="{Binding RelativeSource=
                                {RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                AncestorLevel=1, 
                                AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                Converter={StaticResource gridConverter}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Для таблиц я сделал стиль по умолчанию, внутри которого находится стиль для полосы прокрутки. В этом стиле находится триггер, который для вертикальной полосы прокрутки устанавливает толщину верхней границы, равную высоте заголовков колонок.

Высота заголовков колонок в гриде вычисляется с использованием специального конвертера, который я назвал `GridConverter` и поместил его экземпляр в ресурсы стиля. Он конвертирует таблицу `DataGrid` в значение типа `Thickness`, которое нужно присвоить толщине границ вертикальной полосы прокрутки. Код класса `GridConverter` получился такой:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
    object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  if (targetType == typeof(Thickness))
  {
    if (value is DataGrid)
    {
      var grid = (DataGrid)value;
      var presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>(grid);

      return new Thickness(0, - presenter.ActualHeight, 0, 0);
    }
    else
      return new Thickness();
  }

  return null;
}

public static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject current) where T : DependencyObject
{
  if (current == null) 
    return null;

  int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current);

  for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
  {
    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);

    if (child is T) 
      return (T)child;

    T result = FindVisualChild<T>(child);

    if (result != null) 
      return result;
  }

  return null;
}
```

Этот конвертер в визуальном дереве таблицы рекурсивно ищет шаблон заголовков колонок, берёт его актуальную высоту и возвращает нужную толщину границ, опираясь на эту актуальную высоту.